# Javascript count same array of object values based on two values

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let's say we have an array of object like this

```
const studentRecord = [
 {
   name: 'John Doe',
   gender: 'Male',
   grade: '85'
 },{
   name: 'Steve Doe',
   gender: 'Male',
   grade: '85'
 },{
   name: 'Jane Doe',
   gender: 'Male',
   grade: '90'
 },{
   name: 'Mary Jane',
   gender: 'Female',
   grade: '85'
 },
]
```

I would like to count all students that are male that have the same grade and female students with the same grade something like this would be the output...

```
 85: {
       Male: 2,
       Female: 1,
     }
 90: {
       Female:1
     }
```

I only have this code so far

```
    const foo = {};
    studentRecord.reduce((prevVal, currentVal) => {
      foo[currentVal['gender']] = (foo[currentVal['gender']] || 0) + 1;
    });
```

Which only outputs
 `{Male: 2, Female: 2}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When reducing into an object, create an object at the *grade* property first, if it doesn't exist. Then create an object at that grade's `Male` or `Female` property if it doesn't exist, and increment it:

```js
const studentRecord = [
 {
   name: 'John Doe',
   gender: 'Male',
   grade: '85'
 },{
   name: 'Steve Doe',
   gender: 'Male',
   grade: '85'
 },{
   name: 'Jane Doe',
   gender: 'Male',
   grade: '90'
 },{
   name: 'Mary Jane',
   gender: 'Female',
   grade: '85'
 },
];

const results = studentRecord.reduce((a, { gender, grade }) => {
  if (!a[grade]) {
    a[grade] = {};
  }
  a[grade][gender] = (a[grade][gender] || 0) + 1;
  return a;
}, {});
console.log(results);
```

Or, [without reduce](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qaGjS7-qWzg):

```js
const studentRecord = [
 {
   name: 'John Doe',
   gender: 'Male',
   grade: '85'
 },{
   name: 'Steve Doe',
   gender: 'Male',
   grade: '85'
 },{
   name: 'Jane Doe',
   gender: 'Male',
   grade: '90'
 },{
   name: 'Mary Jane',
   gender: 'Female',
   grade: '85'
 },
];

const results = {};
for (const { gender, grade } of studentRecord) {
  if (!results[grade]) {
    results[grade] = {};
  }
  results[grade][gender] = (results[grade][gender] || 0) + 1;
}
console.log(results);
```

Comment: thank you so much! worked like a charm. just a thought though can this be achieved dynamically? like you can choose which property in the object you would like to count

Comment: Sure, just make a function which takes the property to look up, and use bracket notation to look it up when accessing the record

Answer (score 1):

Your code has the right idea regarding the gender key, but is missing the grade keys, which is necessary to produce the desired nested object.

The approach below checks whether a grade key exists yet and adds it if it doesn't. Then, it increments the appropriate gender for that key.

```js
const studentRecords = [{ name: 'John Doe', gender: 'Male', grade: '85' }, { name: 'Steve Doe', gender: 'Male', grade: '85' }, { name: 'Jane Doe', gender: 'Male', grade: '90' }, { name: 'Mary Jane', gender: 'Female', grade: '85' }];

const byGrade = studentRecords.reduce((a, e) => {
  if (!(e.grade in a)) {
    a[e.grade] = {};
  }
  
  a[e.grade][e.gender] = ++a[e.grade][e.gender] || 1;
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(byGrade);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
const studentRecord = [
 {
   name: 'John Doe',
   gender: 'Male',
   grade: '85'
 },{
   name: 'Steve Doe',
   gender: 'Male',
   grade: '85'
 },{
   name: 'Jane Doe',
   gender: 'Male',
   grade: '90'
 },{
   name: 'Mary Jane',
   gender: 'Female',
   grade: '85'
 },
]

const grades = {};

studentRecord.map(e => { if(!grades[e.grade]) grades[e.grade] = {Male:0,Female:0}; });

studentRecord.map(e => grades[e.grade][e.gender]++ );

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(grades)
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```